# NSToolbar - Toolbar Space Item - breaking default constraints

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, autolayout

If i change the size of NSToolbar from application, via small size, icons & text, the app brakes on unsatisfied constraints (tried to turn off autolayout, or let the app generate its layout)

My window consist of a toolbar and a (left / right) split view inside

```
[81687:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x100635620 h=--& v=--& V:[NSToolbarItemViewer:0x101b4d930(5)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x100634b30 h=--& v=-&- V:|-(11)-[_NSToolbarSpace:0x101b49a00]   (Names: '|':NSToolbarItemViewer:0x101b4d930 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x100634ad0 h=--& v=-&- V:[_NSToolbarSpace:0x101b49a00]-(12)-|   (Names: '|':NSToolbarItemViewer:0x101b4d930 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x100634b30 h=--& v=-&- V:|-(11)-[_NSToolbarSpace:0x101b49a00]   (Names: '|':NSToolbarItemViewer:0x101b4d930 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

When i visualize the constraint error

[image]

**Edit : Looks like "Toolbar Space Item" is breaking the constraint, if i remove it, i runs fine**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug, i ended up adding my own space item, using a blank NSView

Comment: I had a similar problem. And what fixed the problem for me was removing all flexible spaces from both the *Default Toolbar* and the *Allowed Toolbar Items*. When I added the **Flexible Space** again from the object browser the warning disappeared.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be one of those bugs that will never be fixed.

Comment: Based on my experiences, **Flexible Space** can be fixed by the way @Besi pointed out. However **Space** item will always leads to contrain conflict whenever being added back to the default toolbar

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. And what fixed the problem for me was removing all flexible spaces from both the *Default Toolbar* and the *Allowed Toolbar Items*. When I added the **Flexible Space** again from the object browser the warning disappeared.

In my Git diff I see that the structure seems to have changed somewhat:

[image: git diff]

Comment: not works for me, after adding Flexible  Space from object browser error starts showing again